# Can "simultas" simply mean "task," or does it always connote hostility?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, meaning, nuance, hyginus

In his tale of Æetes, Hyginus writes

> Itaque Æeta Jasoni hanc simultatem constituit: Si vellet pellem auratam auferre, tauros æripedes … jungeret …

Lewis & Short gives this definition for *simultas*:

> 1. A hostile encounter, dissension, enmity, rivalry, jealousy, grudge, hatred, animosity
> 2. a strife, contest

At first I tried to translate the Hyginus passage

> And so Ætes conceived this enmity for Jason: If he wanted, etc.

But that doesn't make any sense at all.

In *The Myths of Hyginus*, Mary Grant translates [this passage](http://www.theoi.com/Text/HyginusFabulae1.html#22)

> And so Aeetes appointed this task for Jason: If he wished, etc.

Is "task" a recognized meaning of *simultas* that Lewis & Short just leave out? And, if so, does it have a connotation of hostility, as the other definitions might suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Contest" from L&S's definition 2 works pretty well here: "he appointed this contest for Jason". "Issued this challenge" might be better yet. I think this is a slightly unusual use of *simultas* in that this "contest" is not between Jason and anyone else, so the word doesn't seem to convey a specific connotation of hostility as it otherwise would.

Comment: I've just encountered *simultas* in another passage of Hygin in a similar context: *[Sphinx] regi Creontem simultatem constituit, si carmen, quod posuisset, aliquis interpretatus esset, se inde abire*. So perhaps "challenge" would be a good translation as well, at least for cases in which there isn't another contestant.